# Windows Server 20120 R2 Std on Intel i7 system

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Installing Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard on Intel i7 CPU with good RAM.

Is this CPU supported by this version of Windows?

Here is my exact configuration

Core i7 - 4th
Giga h81 s2ps
1 tb hdd
8 gb corsair ram

Thanks,

Sandesh

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: edited my question. :)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be supported? This is enough, but it of course depends on what you will be using it for.

Comment: Our vendors response is "Its not supported". Will use it to host few IIS sites in intranet for 40-50 people only.

Comment: Did they explain it?

Comment: Its a desktop system for client OS's only, was the reply.

Comment: Then fire them - obviously incompetent. Desktop systems DO have certain issues (uptime, long term stability) but support for a modern OS is not one of them. THere are a TON of reasons to do that - for example as development system. For some programming you must work on a server OS (or at least it is best).

Comment: Your answer is literally in the first result of a google search for "server 2012 system requirements". You didn't take one moment to try to answer your question on your own. Downvote.

Comment: minimum system requirement says, CPU with 1.4 ghz may work but didn't get any results for i7 cpu specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows supports this CPU but depending on the actual system (including mainboard and case) the CPU is in, it might not be a particularly good idea to use it as a production server system (hence the "client OS" remark by your provider).

Desktop systems with desktop CPUs and mainboards in desktop cases make lousy servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider if using a desktop PC, without RAID 1 is secure and resilient enough if a disk failure occurs...

Servers are usually redundant and made for running 24/7, which a desktop PC isn't.

That being said you should be able to do it...